# how to do negative filtering on jquery plugin data tables?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

hi I am using the data tables plugin for jquery and I would like to modify my server side script to allow for negative searches ex. !foo. and it would show everything but foo. I have some code that I have written but it doesn't seem to be working and im not sure why. i can filter regularly but when i use a !foo it just returns everything in the table.

```
$sWhere = "";
if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $aWords = preg_split('/\s+/', $_GET['sSearch']);
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";

    for ( $j=0 ; $j<count($aWords) ; $j++ ) {
        if ( $aWords[$j] != "" ) {
            if(substr($aWords[$j], 0, 1) == "!") {
                    $notString = substr($aWords[$j], 1);
                    $sWhere .= "(";
                    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
                            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." NOT LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $notString )."%' OR ";
                    }
            } else {
                $sWhere .= "(";
                for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
                        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $aWords[$j] )."%' OR ";
                }
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
            $sWhere .= ") AND ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -4 );
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The DataTables plugin has a built in filter function that works with regular expressions. If you can use that you could try a negative lookahead assertion.

```
^((?!foo).)*$
```

Take a look at the example here and see if this is what you need:
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/regex.html

Comment: thank you for the response but unfortunately that is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

All of that code you've pasted is in PHP so it's not using DataTables framework to search at all and I am going to assume you have server side processing enabled.

In order to do a negative filter from server side using SQL `NOT LIKE` would be fine, as you've tried to do, but all your positive and negative filter code is handled in the same digest loop. I would add another `$_GET` like `$_GET['sSearch_type']` to handle your negative filters in a completely separate loop. As long as you can reproduce the query in PHP MyAdmin (or whichever SQL manager you use) there won't be any problem setting up the query in a separate loop using a separate `$_GET` to control the type of search.

**For those of you who want to *actually* use DataTables to filter and need a negative filter expression:** @Nate is correct about using a `regex`expression but the implementation isn't discussed.

There are 2 API ways that I know of to use a regex in this manner. Either `fnFilter()` or `search()`

`fnFilter()` is deprecated, you can still use it but it's better to use the `search()` API funcion which was written to replace `fnFilter()`.

Docs:

- fnFilter() - https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnFilter
- search() - https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

**EXAMPLE:**

```
// case insensitive filter a column for all
// values that don't match 'closed'
column.search( '^(?!closed).*$', true, false, true ).draw();
```

**EXAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION:**

```
/**
 * This example creates a select box filter which 
 * appends to the thead cell of the 3rd column 
 * from the left (i.e. column at index 2). The values
 * of the select <option></option> are generated
 * automatically based on the column's real values
 * except for the 2 top most filters. The first is "All"
 * which passes and empty string to the regex filter, 
 * and the second top most filter is "All Open Projects"
 * which triggers the negative regex filter to remove 
 * all rows where the column value is set to "Closed" 
 * or "closed"
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#report-table').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column_index = this[0][0],
                    column = this,
                    not_closed = 'not_closed',
                    select = $('<select id="status_col_filter" style="margin-left:10px;"><option value="">All</option><option value="'+ not_closed +'">All Open Projects</option></select>');

                if (column_index === 2) {
                    select
                        .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex( $(this).val() );
                            if (val === not_closed) {
                                // negative regex for all open status projects
                                column.search( '^(?!closed).*$', true, false, true ).draw();
                            } else {
                                // regular positive regex - filter by column value
                                column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();
                            }
                        });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```